# What should I do to make matplotlib display Chinese in spyder?

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

> Pycharm is OK. But it couldn't run successfully in Spyder which is from Anaconda3. In Spyder, it can not display the Chinese title.My code is as follows.What should I do to make matplotlib display Chinese in Spyder?Thanks for any help.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import pylab as pl


'''
针对matplotlib显示中文的办法
只需添加下面三行代码
'''
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams["font.sans-serif"] = ["Microsoft YaHei"]
mpl.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False

def func(x, p):
    '''
    数据拟合所需要的函数
    A*sin(2*K*np.pi*x + theta)
    '''
    A, k, theta = p
    return A*np.sin(2*k*np.pi*x + theta)

def residuals(p , y, x):
    '''
    实验数据和拟合函数之差，p为拟合需要的参数
    '''
    return (y-func(x, p))

x = np.linspace(0, -2*np.pi, 100)
A, k, theta = 10, 0.34, np.pi/6  # 真实数据的函数参数
y0 = func(x, [A, k, theta])  # 真实数据
y1 = y0 + 2 * np.random.randn(len(x))  # 加入噪声之后的数据

p0 = [7, 0.2, 0]  # 第一次猜测的函数拟合函数
# 调用leastsq进行数据拟合
# residuals为计算误差的函数
# p0为拟合参数的初始值
# args为需要拟合的实验数据
plsq = leastsq(residuals, p0, args=(y1, x))
print("真实参数-->", [A, k, theta])
print("拟合参数-->", plsq[0])    
pl.plot(x, y0, label = "真实数据")
pl.plot(x, y1, label = "带噪声的实验数据")
pl.plot(x, func(x, plsq[0]), label = "拟合数据")
pl.legend()
pl.legend()
pl.show()
```

[This is the picture that I get in Spyder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rajq4.png)

[This is the picture that I get in Pycharm and I want to get this in Spyder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaGbv.png)

Answer (score 1):

I also met this problem, tried serval method for days. Finally, Change "SimHei" for "Microsoft YaHei", and it's successful.

step1: find your font path:
/Users/***/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf

step2: copy font to step1
cp /Users/***/Downloads/msyhbd.ttf  (Microsoft YaHei)

step3: clear cache:
rm /Users/***/.matplotlib

step4: restart spyder (restart python)

step5: modify code:

plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Microsoft YaHei']

plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False

done ~， you can see Chinese in matplot.

Maybe there is some bug for spyder to support font "SimHei", I guess so.